# Scroll to element in layout with horizontal overflow (with onclick or anchor)

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll

What's the best approach for adding an onclick event to trigger a scroll for an element that has horizontal overflow?

**Premise:** I'd like to add an anchor nav that allows a user to jump to specific milestones in a timeline UI. I'm working from this example [EnvatoTuts](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/building-a-horizontal-timeline-with-css-and-javascript--cms-28378). By grabbing the first instance of a year I'm attaching an ID to the milestone and building out an anchor nav.

**Things I've tried:** It seems most information is in regards to vertically scrolling the html or body, where as I'm looking to only scroll horizontally within div.

- I tried using smooth scroll, but because the action is horizontal the browser 'jumps' down to the anchor
- I tried using `position:fixed` on the anchor nav, but this takes the nav out of the parent container, attaching it to the viewport
- I tried using `translateZ(0)` on the container element (`.timeline`), but `position:fixed` does not actually work on the anchor nav because the position essentially reverts back to relative
- I tried using a plugin for scrolling ([sweet-scroll](https://tsuyoshiwada.github.io/sweet-scroll/#examples)), but couldn't figure out how to trigger scrolling with the nav outside of the target container

Here's the javascript I've used to set an ID and build the anchor nav:

```
  markFirstYear("2014", "m06");
  markFirstYear("2015", "m07");
  markFirstYear("2016", "m08");
  markFirstYear("2017", "m09");
  markFirstYear("2018", "m10");

  function markFirstYear(year, id) {
    var elems = $('.timeline .year').filter(function(){
     return this.textContent.trim() === year
    }).first().parent().parent().attr('id', id);
  }

  var sweetScroll = new SweetScroll({
    horizontal: true,
    vertical: false,
  }, ".timeline");
```

And the subsequent HTML for nav:

```
<div class="arrows">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#m06" data-scroll>2014</a></li>
    <li><a href="#m07" data-scroll>2015</a></li>
    <li><a href="#m08" data-scroll>2016</a></li>
    <li><a href="#m09" data-scroll>2017</a></li>
  </ul>
  <button class="arrow arrow__prev disabled" disabled><img src="/img/arrow_prev.svg" alt="Previous"></button>
  <button class="arrow arrow__next"><img src="/img/arrow_next.svg" alt="Next"></button>  
</div>
```

I'd be happy to implement any solution such as:

1. Keeping the nav div (`.arrows`) in the viewport contained by its parent div of `.timeline` while allowing the container to scroll independently at all times **or**
2. Trigger scrolling via the nav outside the scroll container. I tried using [sweet-scroll](https://tsuyoshiwada.github.io/sweet-scroll/#examples) however, when I move the anchor nav outside of the scroll container `.timeline` the anchor links stop working. **or**
3. Add a click event to the anchors that uses CSS translate to scroll the container to appropriate position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved for the above issues with a bit of CSS:

```
.arrows {
  position:absolute; 
  width:100vw; 
  left:50%; 
  -webkit-transform:translateX(-50%); 
          transform:translateX(-50%);
}
```

The key is the width value of `100vw`. It keeps the nav centered even though the div has an x overflow that goes beyond the edge of the viewport.